# Inserted 3k rows into MsSql, now querying them times out

Tags: sql-server

I have a table which had about 4k rows, then I inserted 3k rows from another table into it. The import have caused me problems, querying for new data never seems to finish. And I cannot figure out how to fix it and where to search for the error cause.

I ran for example a simple

```
SELECT TOP 1 FROM SomeTable WHERE SomeColumn IS Null
```

to get one of the new rows (the SomeColumn is only null in the newly inserted rows), but its still in executing state after 10 minutes.

When I query for the old rows it returns data immediately.

Comment: There might still be some locks on your table (how to check it is described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11034504/show-all-current-locks-from-get-lock-on-mysql )
Have you tried restarting your MySQL server?
... Or your harddisk is failing, you might want to check the syslog (and the drive's SMART status)

Comment: Some problem with the insert. I did not find out what it was, as it seemed ok when I ran it. I ended up killing all ongoing processes, the new rows was gone, but the table seem to be in good shape again.  http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/02/06/sql-server-quickest-way-to-kill-all-threads-kill-all-user-session-kill-all-processes/

Comment: (someone changed the tag to mysql, but this is on a mssql server)

Comment: Oh, sry, my mistake...